# Python - Count row between interval in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with a date, engine, energy and max power column. Let's say that the dataset is composed of 2 machines and a depth of one month. Each machine has a maximum power (say 100 for simplicity). Each machine with 3 operating states (between Pmax and 80% of Pmax either nominal power, between 80% and 20% of Pmax or drop in load and finally below 20% of Pmax at 0 we consider that the machine stops below 20%)

The idea is to know, by period and machine, the number of times the machine has operated in the 2nd interval (between 80% and 20% of the Pmax). If a machine drops to stop it should not be counted and if it returns from stop it should not be counted either.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.ma.extras import _ezclump as ez


data = {'date': ['01/01/2020', '01/02/2020', '01/03/2020', '01/04/2020', '01/05/2020', '01/06/2020', '01/07/2020', '01/08/2020', '01/09/2020', '01/10/2020', '01/11/2020', '01/12/2020', '01/13/2020', '01/14/2020', '01/15/2020', '01/16/2020', '01/17/2020', '01/18/2020', '01/19/2020', '01/20/2020', '01/21/2020', '01/22/2020', '01/23/2020', '01/24/2020', '01/25/2020', '01/26/2020', '01/27/2020', '01/28/2020', '01/29/2020', '01/30/2020', '01/31/2020',
                 '01/01/2020', '01/02/2020', '01/03/2020', '01/04/2020', '01/05/2020', '01/06/2020', '01/07/2020', '01/08/2020', '01/09/2020', '01/10/2020', '01/11/2020', '01/12/2020', '01/13/2020', '01/14/2020', '01/15/2020', '01/16/2020', '01/17/2020', '01/18/2020', '01/19/2020', '01/20/2020', '01/21/2020', '01/22/2020', '01/23/2020', '01/24/2020', '01/25/2020', '01/26/2020', '01/27/2020', '01/28/2020', '01/29/2020', '01/30/2020', '01/31/2020'],
                'engine': ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',
                           'b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b',],
                'energy': [100,100,100,100,100,80,80,60,60,60,60,60,90,100,100,50,50,40,20,0,0,0,20,50,60,100,100,50,50,50,50,
                            50,50,100,100,100,80,80,60,60,60,60,60,0,0,0,50,50,100,90,50,50,50,50,50,60,100,100,50,50,100,100],
                'pmax': [100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,
                         100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]
                }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'engine', 'energy', 'pmax'])

df['date'] = df['date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

df = df.set_index('date')


df['inter'] = df['energy'].apply(lambda x: 2 if x >= 80 else (1 if x < 80 and x >= 20 else 0 ))

liste = []
engine_off = ez((df['inter'] == 1).to_numpy())
for i in engine_off:
    if df.iloc[(i.start)-1, 3] == 0:
        engine_off.remove(i)
    elif df.iloc[(i.stop), 3] == 0:
        engine_off.remove(i)
    else:
        liste.append([df['engine'][i.start],df.index[i.start],df.index[i.stop], i.stop - i.start])

dfend = pd.DataFrame(liste, columns=['engine','begin','end','nb_heure'])

dfend['month'] = dfend['begin'].dt.month_name()

dfgroupe = dfend.set_index('begin').groupby(['engine','month']).agg(['mean','max','min','std','count','sum']).fillna(1)
```

Either I recover my data in a Dataframe, I classify for each line the associated energy in an interval (2 for nominal operation, 1 for intermediate and 0 for stop)

Then I check if each row in the interval == 1 column allowing me to retrieve a list of slices with the start and end of each slice.

Then I loop to check that each element before or after my slice is different from 0 to exclude the decreases for stop or return from stop.

Then I create a dataframe from the list, then I average, sum, etc.

The problem is that my list has only 4 drops while there are 5 drops. This comes from the 4 slice (27.33)

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Can  you provide a simpler data and expected output just so it's easier to verify the result?

Comment: I can't give more simple data than this because this dataframe contain all the exceptions to treat.
I'd like to get output dataframe exactly like this output dfgroupe = dfend.set_index('begin').groupby(['engine','month']).agg(['mean','max','min','std','count','sum']).fillna(1), but the problem it's that my script count only 4 drops but in fact there are 5 drops because this EZ function
check only if the inter value == 1 but if you look the Dataframe you can see that there are this slice its count only for 1 but in fact its 2 because there are A and B engine

Comment: Maybe i've to groupby my df before to apply the functions but I can't apply all theses functions after groupby I don't know how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it, I tried to use your way with groups but ended up to do it slightly differently

```
# another way to create inter, probably faster on big dataframe
df['inter'] = pd.cut(df['energy']/df['pmax'], [-1,0.2, 0.8, 1.01], 
                     labels=[0,1,2], right=False)

# mask if inter is equal to 1 and groupby engine
gr = df['inter'].mask(df['inter'].eq(1)).groupby(df['engine'])

# create a mask to get True for the rows you want
m = (df['inter'].eq(1)   # the row are 1s
     & ~gr.ffill().eq(0) # the row before 1s is not 0
     & ~gr.bfill().eq(0) # the row after 1s is not 0
    )

#create dfend with similar shape to yours
dfend = (df.assign(date=df.index) #create a column date for the agg
           .where(m) # replace the rows not interesting by nan
           .groupby(['engine', #groupby per engine
                     m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()]) # and per group of following 1s
           .agg(begin=('date','first'), #agg date with both start date
                end = ('date','last'))  # and end date
         )
# create the colum nb_hours (although here it seems to be nb_days)
dfend['nb_hours'] = (dfend['end'] - dfend['begin']).dt.days+1

print (dfend)
                  begin        end  nb_hours
engine inter                                
a      2     2020-01-08 2020-01-12         5
       4     2020-01-28 2020-01-31         4
b      4     2020-01-01 2020-01-02         2
       6     2020-01-20 2020-01-25         6
       8     2020-01-28 2020-01-29         2
```

and you got the three segment for engine b as required, then you can

```
#create dfgroupe
dfgroupe = (dfend.groupby(['engine', #groupby engine
                           dfend['begin'].dt.month_name()]) #and month name
                 .agg(['mean','max','min','std','count','sum']) #agg
                 .fillna(1)
           )
print (dfgroupe)
                nb_hours                            
                    mean max min       std count sum
engine begin                                        
a      January  4.500000   5   4  0.707107     2   9
b      January  3.333333   6   2  2.309401     3  10
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the following terminology:
- 80 <= energy <= 100  --->  df['inter'] == 2, normal mode. 
- 20 <= energy < 80  --->  df['inter'] == 1, intermediate mode. 
- 20 > energy  --->  df['inter'] == 0, stop mode.

I reckon you want to find those periods of time in which: 
 
1) The machine is operating in intermediate mode. 
2) You don't want to count if the status is changing from intermediate to stop mode or from stop to intermediate mode.

```
# df['before']: this is to compare each row of df['inter'] with the previous row
# df['after']: this is to compare each row of df['inter'] with the next row
# df['target'] == 1 is when both above mentioned conditions (conditions 1 and 2) are met.
# In the next we mask the original df and keep those times that conditions 1 and 2 are met, then we group by machine and month, and after that obtain the min, max, mean, and so on.

df['before'] = df['inter'].shift(periods=1, fill_value=0)
df['after'] = df['inter'].shift(periods=-1, fill_value=0)
df['target'] = np.where((df['inter'] == 1) & (np.sum(df[['inter', 'before', 'after']], axis=1) > 2), 1, 0)
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
mask = df['target'] == 1
df_group = df[mask].groupby(['engine', 'month']).agg(['mean', 'max', 'min', 'std', 'count', 'sum'])
```